# On double click, event is not getting call on disabled input text field in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, vuejs2

I am working on cross browser issue:-
i have one input text field and its in disabled mode. 
i want to fire an event on double click and make field in enabled mode but event is not getting fire on double click in firefox

in chrome : below code is working fine on double click

```
document.addEventListener("dblclick", this.editInputField);
```

but for firefox, no event is getting fire on double click on disabled textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firfox will not fire mouse events for disabled elements. You should create a cover like a div in front of it and when dblclicking on the cover then turn the disabled elements to enabled.

UPDATE:
Test it here

```js
var inp = document.querySelector('.myInput');
inp.nextElementSibling.addEventListener('dblclick', function () {
  inp.removeAttribute('disabled');
  inp.focus();
});
```

```css
input[disabled] + .cover {
  display: block;
}

.cover {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 25px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="myInput" disabled/>
  <div class="cover"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: but text is not get selected on click on div. any solution?

Comment: I have posted an example , pls check if it's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does not allow interactions with a disabled element. One solution you can try is using a wrapper `div` around input and handle the click events on those.

```
<div ondbclick="activateInput">
    <input disabled type="text">
</div>
```